# How to export address book from Zimbra?

Tags: email-server, migration, zimbra

I want to export all users' contacts (Address book) in `csv` format for migration purpose. 
Zimbra is runing on ubuntu and I want to do this from cli.
How shall I proceed? 
I have refereed to this [link](https://www.zimbra.com/desktop7/help/en_US/Contacts/Exporting_Address_Books.htm) but this is not an option for me.

Kindly let me know if you want any more details.

Comment: What is your migration target? What are you hoping to migrate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you want to do this on a Zimbra server, but if it is a server you can use zmmailbox with a getRestUrl for almost all things that can be done in the web interface. Become the zimbra user

```
zmmailbox -z -m mail@domain.com -t 0 getRestURL "//contacts?fmt=csv"
```

This is a basic csv export, mainly compatible with Zimbra. You can make the exports more compatible with other applications by replacing the csv with one of the following options:

- zimbra-csv
- yahoo-csv
- thunderbird-csv
- outlook-2000-csv
- outlook-2003-csv

To make an outlook 2003 compatible export you the command changes to:

```
zmmailbox -z -m mail@domain.com -t 0 getRestURL "//contacts?fmt=outlook-2003-csv"
```

To make an export from a different adressbook, you can use the name of that adressbook f.e.:

```
zmmailbox -z -m mail@domain.com -t 0 getRestURL "//privatecontacts?fmt=outlook-2003-csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

On the command line (as the `zimbra` user) you can use the commands `zmprov` and `zmmailbox` to access user accounts, folders (mail, contacts, calendars) and folder content.

Use

```
zimbra@mail:~$ zmprov help
```

or

```
zimbra@mail:~$ zmmailbox help
```

to see what commands are available.

As an example for accessing a user's contacts from the main contacts folder use:

```
zmmailbox -z -m mail@domain.com getAllContacts -f "/Contacts"
```

But this command does not provide csv output, so read on.

---

There is also a [Rest API](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zimbra_REST_API_Reference) for accessing Zimbra content.

The parameter `fmt` only takes the following values:

- `csv`
- `json`
- `xml`
- `tgz`
- `zip`

If you are using `fmt=csv` you can additionally specify the csv format with the parameter `csvfmt` and one of the following values:

- `zimbra-csv`
- `yahoo-csv`
- `thunderbird-csv`
- `outlook-2000-csv`
- `outlook-2003-csv`

So the entire command could look as follows:

```
zmmailbox -z -m mail@domain.com -t 0 getRestURL "/Contacts?fmt=csv&csvfmt=outlook-2003-csv"
```

Additional information can be found [here](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zimbra_REST_API_Reference:Get_Contacts)